# How to fix: ERROR: column u0_.id does not exist

Tags: symfony, docker-compose, api-platform.com

I'm working with the API Platform and tried installing the [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/). When I went to my API platform admin it shows me a server communication error and my console says:

```
ERROR:  column u0_.id does not exist at character 8
```

I googled it and found stackoverflow.com but found no solution for my specific problem.

This is my User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 */
class user implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return [
            'ROLE_USER'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->password

        ]);
    }
    public function unserialize($string)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->password
            ) = unserialize($string, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }
}
```

Here is the full error message:

```
db_1        | 2019-11-08 14:01:56.997 UTC [323] ERROR:  column u0_.id does not exist at character 8
db_1        | 2019-11-08 14:01:56.997 UTC [323] STATEMENT:  SELECT u0_.id AS id_0, u0_.email AS email_1, u0_.username AS username_2, u0_.password AS password_3 FROM user u0_ ORDER BY u0_.id ASC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Are you sure your database's schema is up-to-date ?

Comment: yeah, I run docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force